# One to One mapping of data in the row in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have dataset looks like this

[image]

And I want the output of this data frame like this. So it's kind of one to one mapping of row values. Assume `option1` and `option2` has same comma separated values.

[image]

Please let me know how do I achieve this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split (explode) pandas dataframe string entry to separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `zip()` function from the standard Python library and the `explode()` method from Pandas dataframe like that :

```py
df["option1"] = df["option1"].str.split(",")
df["option2"] = df["option2"].str.split(",")
df["option3"] = df["option3"]*max(df["option1"].str.len().max(), df["option2"].str.len().max())
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda x: list(zip(x[0], x[1], x[2])), axis=1).explode().to_list(), columns=df.columns)
new_df
```